# Approximate solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

If one has a differential equation for $y(x)$.

If this differential equation has two solutions one for $x\ll a$ and the other for $a\ll x$, where $a$ is constant real value. My question is at what point does each solution become invalid? How close can $x$ get to $a$ before a solution becomes invalid.

Comment: What is the differential equation in question?

Comment: I don't think it depends on the differential equation. I am just wondering at what interval is each solution valid.

Comment: It depends on your approximation and on your application.  It sounds like one approximation in your question is valid in the limit $x \to \infty$, so, in a sense, if you're doing anything other than taking a limit, the approximation is invalid.  Without error estimates on the approximation it's impossible to know any more.

Comment: You title says approximation but I don't see a reference to approximation anywhere in the question. But what I think you're looking for is known as bifurcation theory.